# What Causes ComboBox Text to be Selected

Tags: .net, winforms, combobox, windows-forms-designer, tablelayoutpanel

What would cause the last 4 rows of comboboxes to have the text selected? There is nothing that I am aware of adding/changing that would cause this and it is consistent each time this window is opened. No input is given for it to display this way. This started happening after I placed the labels and comboboxes into a table layout panel. Before, all the items were drag/dropped into place with no containers.

Looking at it now, I believe the left column, at least, should be a listbox instead, but that doesn't explain why the text is highlighted.

[image: Selected text in comboboxes]

Comment: You need to share code if you want us to help you

Comment: It probably has something to do with the `focus`. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1140277/5734097) or set the property `DropDownStyle` to `DropDownList` (of the comboboxes,).